# webview for user interface in android

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, user-interface

I was searching for how to use swf file in android and most of the answer suggested me to use webview and an simple html file.

Now i think We can easily put css and javascript files in asset folder and then we can use them in an html5 code.

Looking at the power of HTML5, This will make app development for a web designer very easy job !

I just want to know that is it good to use this approach to build a good user interface in android ? Are there any technical pros/cons behind it ? will i miss some features provided by android ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of frameworks that allow you to write native android applications using `HTML/CSS/JavaScript` only. Here some of them :

- [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)
- [Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/)
- [Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/platform/titanium-sdk/)

I've never used any of them, so I can't say if it's good or bad idea to write android apps this way, but here you can find a good session about it [HTML5 versus Android](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4f2Zky_YyyQ).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
this frameworks does the same what i was asking for. 

But we can do some easy task without using their sdk. 
My question is that are there any technical drawback of this approach ?

Answer (score 0):

There are pros & cons of using cross platforms. As per my point of view you shouldn't go for loading of everything in WebView.

I still recommend you native app approach because of following points :

- WebView is one of the UI control in Android SDK. So, it will have
  limitation of memory size and working with CPU utilization. So, you
  might face performance issues in some devices.
- As you know in older era we were used to work with desktop apps and after that everything is shifted to web-application.
- It was
  possible only because our browser(s) gets more features for e.g. more
  memory area, CPU access, threading, individual Processing (like
  google chrome) etc...
- in-short, web browsers gets more smart and get treated as separate application. Now a days web-application can have mostly similar
  performance as desktop apps. So, everything is now shifted to
  web-application development.

This era will come in to Mobile development in later stage. but currently we are in middle stage of Mobile development and Cross platform development.  So until and unless Web-View control of any platform (iOS / Android) gets more powerful, we can not totally relay on that.

I Hope I explain it properly :)